# how to get TextBlock value inside resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I have following text-block in resource dictionary

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textSampleVal" Text="{Binding textSamVal}" />
```

How to get this `textSampleVal` value from ViewModel class

Comment: Question cannot be answered from given information. Binding will dynamically correspond to your `DataContext`.

Comment: First of all, if your `TextBlock` placed inside a resource dictionary then you need to use `x:Key` instead of `x:Name`. And secondly, `textSamVal` should be property of the view model set as `DataContext` of the `TextBlock`, so you already have the value in view model.

Comment: Why are you defining a textblock in a resource dictionary? That is a very unusual thing to do.

Comment: Note that without `x:Shared="False"` this instance of `TextBlock` cannot be placed in multiple controls.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get this textSampleVal value from ViewModel class

Simply by accessing the `textSampleVal` property that the `TextBlock` binds to.

It doesn't make any difference whether you define the binding in a `ResourceDictionary` or a view, the `TextBlock` will still bind to the `textSamVal` property of its `DataContext` and this is supposed to be the view model.

A view model never "gets" anything from the view, i.e. the view model doesn't know anything about any `TextBlock` elements. The view updates the view model using data bindings.